# Using Grease Pencil (Annotation) from Modal in Blender 2.8

Tags: python, grease-pencil, operator

In my addon, I need to do a bunch of stuff while running modal.  One of those things is drawing with a grease pencil, and then processing the curve.  By grease pencil, I mean just the simple annotation tool.  However, I am not able to get the grease pencil to draw from modal.  If I call my draw_curve() function defined below from a button, it works fine.  But from modal, the cursor does not become a pencil, and I cannot draw.  What am I missing?

(I guess it might have something to do with detecting the left mouse press to actually commence drawing a stroke, but this worked in modal in Blender 2.7x without any further steps, and I'm having trouble figuring out what else 2.8 wants.)

Thanks in advance!

```
class MYADDON_OT_modal_operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myaddon.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Operator"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'D' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            draw_curve()
        elif event.type == 'ESC':
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'} 

def draw_curve():
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.annotation_stroke_placement_view3d = "SURFACE"
    bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name="builtin.annotate")
    bpy.ops.gpencil.annotate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: the gpencil.annotate() call on the last line needs to include the argument "INVOKE_DEFAULT".

```
bpy.ops.gpencil.annotate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```